# Proving that a language given by a CFG is not regular

Tags: regular-languages, formal-grammars, pumping-lemma

Consider the language defined by the following grammar:
$$
\begin{align*}
&S \rightarrow E \\
&S \rightarrow \epsilon \\
&E \rightarrow E+E \\
&E \rightarrow E-E \\
&E \rightarrow \mathsf{STRING} \mid \mathsf{LOCTRAN}(E , \mathsf{DIGITS})
\end{align*}
$$
How can I prove that this language is not regular using the pumping lemma?
I don't know which string to use.

Answer (score 1):

A basic example that is context-free but nonregular is the language $\{ a^nb^n \mid n\ge 0\}$.

Here this structure is hidden inside the language. You can find it using the recursive productions

$$E \rightarrow \mathsf{STRING} \mid \mathsf{LOCTRAN}(E , \mathsf{DIGITS})$$